# detect when user swipes the viewpager from edge of a page

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe

I am sure that there are some posts about it, and I skimmed through them before, but now I cannot find them.

I want to detect the action when the user swipes the viewpager from edge of a page (such as left edge). I want to do some special handling for this kind of swipe, such as showing menu.

Is there any ViewPager built-in(?) support for it? I vaguely remembered it is. Otherwise, I have to implement my own logic to detect those action.

Can anyone point me some info?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you should override few methods of the container of your ViewPager. For example if it is LinearLayout

```
public class Liner extends LinearLayout {

public Liner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

//Remember start points
float mInitX;
float mInitY;
// TouchSlop value
float mSomeValue=20F;
// 
boolean mCatched=false;

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    switch (ev.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        mInitX=ev.getX();
        mInitY=ev.getY();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    mCatched=mInitX<10 && Math.abs(ev.getX()-mInitX)>mSomeValue;

    return mCatched;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if(mCatched){
        //Do all you want here
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

If you combine with [TeRRo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27346452/1555366) anrwer (put his detector inside onTouchEvent()) you may have good result. But best way to use DrawerLayout.

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

Simply check for [edge mask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getEdgeFlags%28%29)

```
public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && ev.getEdgeFlags() == MotionEvent.EDGE_LEFT) {

    }

}
```

Same logic will work if you put the snippet inside `onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` override.

Answer (score 0):

With this example you can control all types of gestures in your ViewPager, Now only you need add some condition for handle the edge in `onSwipeLeft()` and `onSwipeRight()`

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());

public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
    onTouch(e);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    boolean result = false;
    try {
        float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
        float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
        if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                if (diffX > 0) {
                    onSwipeRight();
                } else {
                    onSwipeLeft();
                }
            }
        } else {
           // onTouch(e);
        }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
}
public void onTouch(MotionEvent e) {
}
public void onSwipeRight() {
//call this only if your condition was set
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
//nothing, this means,swipes to left will be ignored
}

public void onSwipeTop() {
}

public void onSwipeBottom() {
}
}
```

Set you custom **OnTouchListener** in your viewpager object:

```
viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener() {
public void onSwipeRight() {
   if(your conditionIsMet){
   // move your pager view to the right
   }
}
});
```

I hope that this help you.