# dx during scrolling with BottomSheetBehavior is zero

Tags: android, swipe, horizontal-scrolling, bottom-sheet, coordinator-layout

I have my custom BottomSheetBehavior:

```
public class CustomBehavior extends BottomSheetBehavior {

    public CustomBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedPreScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, View 
    child, View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed) {
        super.onNestedPreScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dx, dy, 
        consumed);
    }
}
```

And I use it in my xml code.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp" 
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        app:layout_behavior=
            "com.hackspace.bottomsheetproblem.CustomBehavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="text"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This behavior works, all nice. But in callback `onNestedPreScroll` dx is always zero. Log something like this:

```
dx: 0, dy: -1
dx: 0, dy: -70
dx: 0, dy: -108
dx: 0, dy: -85
dx: 0, dy: -44
dx: 0, dy: -16
dx: 0, dy: 16
dx: 0, dy: 44
dx: 0, dy: 62
dx: 0, dy: 84
dx: 0, dy: 58
dx: 0, dy: 54
dx: 0, dy: 43
dx: 0, dy: 17
dx: 0, dy: -20
dx: 0, dy: -42
```

Actually, my goal is to make some changes in detection swipes in default BottomSheetBehavior. I need my custom behavior react only on vertical (or almost vertical) swipes, not even on almost horizontal.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem is that `dx` remains zero?

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen Yup. So I can't detect if dx more than dy or not.

Comment: Stupid question, but are you sure that you are logging `dx` correctly?

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen Yes, I'm sure.

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen I only not sure, that I choose right direction of solving my problem.

Comment: What is exactly your scrollable view?

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen Actually it's ViewPager in container

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27346030/detect-when-user-swipes-the-viewpager-from-edge-of-a-page

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen In this post they overrided methods of the container of ViewPager. But in my case events intercepted on the top layer: on the layer of CoordinatorLayout with BottomSheetBehavior, and ViewPager with his container even doesn't got this events.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with this. Maybe this approach can help you: https://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout