# ViewPager in BottomSheetBehavior

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet

I want to change interception of my touches, cause in many cases when I want to swipe ViewPager - actually swipes external container which implements BottomSheetBehavior. I need behavior that will react only on vertical (or almost vertical) swipes and other swipes will handle ViewPager.

Comment: Can I see some code?

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46844954/dx-during-scrolling-with-bottomsheetbehavior-is-zero

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
public class CustomBehavior extends BottomSheetBehavior {

public CustomBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public void onNestedPreScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, View 
child, View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed) {

}
```

}